# Detecting UISwipeGesture on UITableView while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to detect a `UISwipeGesture` on `UITableView` while the tableview is scrolling (i.e. still in motion). The gesture only recognizes when the tableview is at rest. Does anybody know how to solve this?

```
 // Right gesture
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerRight:)];
    [gestureRecognizerRight setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerRight];
```

Comment: Gesture will not be able to recognizes if your view or tableview is in animated state or it is in motion.

Comment: You should have a look into POP from Facebook (https://github.com/facebook/pop). Good chance that this can handle this because they manage to interact with animations which aren't finished.